# dependant combo box resets after new record

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with several dependent combo boxes.  They seem to be working correctly for the most part, ie  offering the right values to chose from and writing them to a table when selected.  The problem is that after I move to the next record and make a choice, it resets the displayed choice in the first record.  However, it does not change the value that was written to the table in the first record.  So, the data is being stored correctly and it is mainly a cosmetic issue.  I've tried playing with on update and on current macros and cant seem to fix the problem.

Please help if you can!

Comment: Is this a bound form, and are the combo boxes bound as well? If the combo boxes are unbound this behaviour would be expected.

Comment: As mentioned above, if the combo boxes have as a control source anything other than a bound field, they will not update by themselves. You have to manually update them or at least requery them when the record changes (that would be the onCurrent event).

Comment: Thanks much, the offenders are bound to the table field where they write the information.  It's like they are actually updating TOO much.  Even after the record gets filled it is still updating the cbo options related to another record.